# How can I programmatically find which USB device triggers a Windows Update?

Tags: api, windows-update

Is there a way to programmatically determine which USB device plugged into my Windows 10 system triggers a Windows 10 update?

WUAPI may provide a solution, but so far I have not been able to find it.  There are also some hack-type ideas (such as parsing setupapi.dev.log for the last install entry), but these would be considered a last resort.

Any guidance on this would be much appreciated.

Thank you.